# Как через Stream создать и заполнить список?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

Есть 0 List.
Можно ли с помощью Stream добавить  в List рандомные(допустим Math.random()) элементы и вернуть его же но уже заполненный ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
Random random = new Random(); // 1
List<Integer> integers = random.ints() // 2
        .limit(10)  // 3
        .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf) // 4
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // 5
```

1. создаем объект типа Random
2. у него вызываем стрим int'ов (так же есть `longs()` и `doubles()` )
3. Ограничиваем стрим 10 элементами (потому что стрим ints() `effectively unlimited`)
4. Создаем объект типа Integer (т.е. делаем box'инг)
5. Собираем все это дело в лист